# Como mudar cor de fundo Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Como faço para alterar a cor de fundo do meu do Visual Studio? Ele está branco quero que seja com fundo preto.

Vejam um exemplo abaixo:

[image: SS]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Está aqui a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-change-fonts-and-colors-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2015&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Tools -> Options -> Environment -> General -> Color Theme

Ou

Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors -> C# -> Item background

No lugar de C#, pode usar outras opções

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: No meu caso, prefiro alterar apenas a cor do Visual Studio... Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 5):

Achei...
Primeiramente vá em:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois em:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]